# Convert SQL to hibernate query using criteria and/or projection (subqueries)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria, projection

Could anyone please help to convert this SQL Query to HQL (using criteria and projection) to have in result `Set<topic> topics`.

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, COUNT(p.id) as count, MAX(p.created_on) as `latest`
FROM topics t
JOIN posts p
  ON t.id = p.topic_id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

My problem is that Hibernate is fetching all data connected to one of columns of the `topic` table (connected table is `users`) - and query takes to much time and unnecessary selects and joins.
Tried to use projections but couldn't.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

### From your code,

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, COUNT(p.id) as count, MAX(p.created_on) as `latest`
FROM topics t
JOIN posts p
  ON t.id = p.topic_id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

You can remove `JOIN` and convert it in `WHERE` condition. Hope it will save you.

### Use this following code

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, COUNT(p.id) as count, MAX(p.created_on) as `latest`
FROM topics t, posts p
WHERE t.id = p.topic_id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY count ASC;
```

Comment: The thing is that I need hql queries with criteria and projections.